# Simulating a coin flip experiment in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, random

I am having trouble getting a program to work properly. The goal is to simulate a coin flip as follows:

Consider a random sequence of numbers: `epsilon_1, epsilon_2, ... , epsilon_N`. Each term in this sequence takes on values `+1` or `-1`, depending on the outcome of the coin toss experiment, heads or tails respectively.

In other words, `for each n = 1,2,...,N:`

`epsilon_n = { +1 with probability = 1/2; and -1 with probability = 1/2.`

Now, I wrote some psuedo-code to help me write this program:

```
# for n = 1,2,...,N:
# flip coin
# if result == "Heads"
    # epsilon_{n} = 1
# else:
    # epsilon_{n} = -1
```

I want to store the values of epsilon for each n (and hence, the result of the experiment for each n) in an array. Here is the program I wrote which hoped to accomplish this:

```
    # array to store outcome of the coin flip
epsilon = np.zeros(N)

# define coin flip experiment
result = [] # result of the experiment
for n in xrange(1, N):
    def coin_flip(): #flip coin for each n = 1,...,N
        flip = random.randint(0,2) 
        if (flip == 0):
            result = "Heads"
        else:
            result = "Tails"
        return result
    if result == "Heads":
        epsilon[n] = 1
    else:
        epsilon[n] = -1

print epsilon
```

The output of this program is an array with the first entry being `0`, and all other entries contain the value `-1`. I specified `N = 100`.

Please, some guidance is all I require. For instance, I think I am on the right track with defining a function for the coin toss experiment. I need it to return the result of the experiment (Heads or Tails), and this need to happen for each `n = 0,1,...,N` but I am unsure of the best method to do so. Then for the result of each individual coin flip, my program must store the value `+1` or `-1` in the array for `epsilon`. Must I include `n` as a parameter for my proposed function?? Am I on the right track here?

Any and all help is very greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So I just want to point out I didn't forget to import libraries like numpy and random. Those are included in my original code but this is actually a part of a larger program and so when I copied and pasted this segment of code the `import random` and `import numpy` was left out

Comment: `np.random.choice([1, -1], N)` will give you N flips (each with 50% chance). Are you avoiding using libraries (to exercise etc.)?

Comment: I left out the libraries by mistake since the code I posted here is in fact a part of a larger program which does something else. My original code imported the proper libraries. Anyways, thanks so much! Is the reason your suggestion works because `0` isn't technically an integer so it is excluded from the interval `[-1,1]`?

Comment: No, that's a list to choose from. If you type `np.random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'], N)` it will return an array of `Heads` and `Tails`. If you type `np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], N)` it will choose a, b or c with equal probability.

Comment: Ohhh my bad I thought that said `random.randint([-1,1], N)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. First, you are creating an empty list called result but later in your code result is a string. So you don't need that part.

```
import numpy as np
import random
N = 10
epsilon = np.zeros(N)
```

This creates an array of length N for you to store the results. Now, your main error is in the loop. You should define that function outside the loop and call it in each iteration:

```
def coin_flip(): #flip coin for each n = 1,...,N
    flip = random.randint(0, 1) 
    if (flip == 0):
        result = "Heads"
    else:
        result = "Tails"
    return result
```

Note that I changed the first line to `random.randint(0, 1)` as it is inclusive on both ends. Now, if you run `coin_flip()` it will return either "Heads" or "Tails".
Change your loop accordingly:

```
for n in xrange(N):
    result = coin_flip()
    if result == "Heads":
        epsilon[n] = 1
    else:
        epsilon[n] = -1
```

This is where you are modifying the epsilon array. Note that in each iteration I am calling `coin_flip()` function and assigning it to `result`.

Now printing epsilon will give you an array as follows:

```
array([ 1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])
```

This is the long way of doing it. Instead, you can do (with random library):

```
[random.choice([1, -1]) for _ in range(N)]
Out[19]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Or (with numpy):

```
np.random.choice([1, -1], N)
Out[20]: array([ 1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response!! I will try it out when I am back at a computer